# Can't get error messages to display when ajax form fails

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms

I am trying to get my form to fail gracefully, but haven not been to get the error function to work at all no matter what put in there. Everything works fine, but if I force an error (eg. giving bad var name), I see the error in the console, but my alerts aren't firing.

Here is my code:

```
$.ajax({
    async: false,
    cache: false,
    type: 'post',

    url: 'dostuff/234',

    data: {
        email: fEmail,
        firstname: fFirstname,
        lastname: fLastname,
        zipcode: fZipcode,
        optout: fOptout
    },
    dataType: "text",
    error: function(xhr, status, error) {
        alert(status);
        alert(xhr.responseText);
    },  
    success: function (response) {
        overlay.appendTo(document.body);
        setTimeout(function(){ finishUp(); }, 3000);    
    }
});
```

Comment: seems the success function is called because it received a correct responsecode, do you confirm ?

Comment: Yes, I confirm. But I can't the error function to call at all even when I know I'm ending it an error and the console confirms.

Comment: add the console error to your question, i think youre misunderstanding sth

Answer (score 0):

If those are defined properly you should be able to get the error msg or success.

```
  data: {
        email: "fEmail",
        firstname: "fFirstname",
        lastname: "fLastname",
        zipcode: "fZipcode",
        optout: "fOptout"
  },
```

```js
var fFirstname = 'test';


$.ajax({
  async: false,
  cache: false,
  type: 'post',

  url: 'dostuff/234',

  data: {
        email: "fEmail",
        firstname: "fFirstname",
        lastname: "fLastname",
        zipcode: "fZipcode",
        optout: "fOptout"
  },
  dataType: "text",
  error: function(xhr, status, error) {
    alert(status);
    alert(xhr.responseText);
  },
  success: function(response) {
    overlay.appendTo(document.body);
    setTimeout(function() {
      finishUp();
    }, 3000);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: They are defined properly, yet I can't get the error function to call when I knowingly send it bad info. The console shows the error and my form doesn't work when I do this, but the error function doesn't run.